# Renaming columns in memsql column name?

Tags: singlestore

in memsql how to rename the column name?
i have tried using the below command it is not working.

ALTER TABLE supp_quote_detail RENAME COLUMN user_support_comments TO user_abc_support_comments ;
ALTER TABLE supp_quote_detail RENAME COLUMN user_support_comments TO user_abc_support_comments text;

Answer (score 2):

ALTER TABLE quote_detail CHANGE  user_quote_support_comments user_cfg_support_comments ;